# MongoDB Java library supporting native aggregation queries

Tags: mongodb

Is there any Java MongoDB library that supports executing native JSON aggregation queries? It seems that `MongoTemplate` from spring-data-mongo and even `MongoClient` all require some kind of Java abstraction. But I would like to simply store my queries in external file in JSON format and just execute them without any extra layer of abstraction so they can be simply reused. Similar to native SQL queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with MongoTemplate.

Here's an example of a Spring Repository :

```
@Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @PostConstruct
    public void addMarketsToDB() {
        if (mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(), MarketEntity.class) == null) {
            URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/marches.json");

            byte[] encoded;
            try {
                encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(url.toURI()));

                BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject();
                obj.append("$eval", new String(encoded));

                mongoTemplate.executeCommand(obj);
            } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
                LOGGER.error("{} addMarketsToDB -> failed to read file", LOG_HEADER);
            }

        }
    }
```